# Struts2 + Jquery datatable compatibility Issue

Tags: jquery, struts2, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables with struts 2.

Previously I was using the struts1 version so this code was working fine but when I upgrade strut with version 2. It's DataTables that is not working.

Actually the some parameter is not getting set properly and believe that parameter is not getting send to server.

Giving the below error on server:

> Unexpected Exception caught setting 'iDisplayLength'on class Error setting expression 'iDisplayLength' with value ['10', ]
>
> Unexpected Exception caught setting 'iDisplayStart' on class Error setting expression 'iDisplayStart' with value ['0', ]

jQuery code is like

```
 $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "listData.action",
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "bProcessing":true,
    "bServerSide":true, 
    "bSortClasses": false,
    "sDom": '<"oTableGenerated"lfirp>t',
    "bStateSave": true,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
```

Comment: There is some code missing, there is no `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` options. Please add the missing code. Also both parameters expect integer, for example: `iDisplayLength: 10` so you cannot use array. See [manual](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) for more information.

Comment: I have tried by setting up both parameter and also created the getter/setter in action class but no luck

Comment: I got the solution for this. we need to give setter as setIDisplayLength(),setIDisplayStart() and setEcho() also. Mean to say that the method name should be proper as per java naming convension